# Return empty object if data is not found into DB

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement Spring endpoint for getting data from DB.

```
@GetMapping("/notification/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getNotificationByTransactionId(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return notificationService
                .findByTransactionId(id)
                .map(g -> NotificationNewDTO.builder()              
                        .id(g.getId()) 
                        .status(g.getStatus())                          
                        .updated_at(g.getUpdated_at())              
                      .build()
                )               
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> notFound().build());
    }
```

Is there some way to return just empty `NotificationNewDTO` object if noting is found into DB?

Comment: Aren't you doing that already here `.orElseGet(() -> notFound().build())` ...?

Comment: this returns status 404 not empty object.

Comment: `return ResponseEntity.ok(notificationService.findByTransactionId(id).map(g -> ...).orElse(NotificationNewDTO.builder().build()))`

Comment: hm... I get `Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace` before map.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the parenthesis in my example. It should be trivial to solve anyway... You didn't *literally* copy the ellipsis, did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would things in two steps : computing the DTO (retrieved or default) and returning it.
It makes things more readable.

Give a default value when you extract `Optional<NotificationNewDTO>` and then invoke  `ResponseEntity.ok()` on the dto :

```
NotificationNewDTO dto  = 
     notificationService
    .findByTransactionId(id) 
    .map(g -> NotificationNewDTO.builder()   // Optional<NotificationNewDTO>
            .id(g.getId()) 
            .status(g.getStatus())                          
            .updated_at(g.getUpdated_at())              
          .build()
     )               
    .orElse(NotificationNewDTO.ofDefaultValue()); // change here

return ResponseEntity.ok(dto); // change here
```

Make it in a single flow is of course possible but it is less clear :

```
return 
    ResponseEntity.ok(
         notificationService
        .findByTransactionId(id) 
        .map(g -> NotificationNewDTO.builder()  
                .id(g.getId()) 
                .status(g.getStatus())                          
                .updated_at(g.getUpdated_at())              
              .build()
         )               
        .orElse(NotificationNewDTO.ofDefaultValue())
    )
```

Comment: What is `ofDefaultValue()`?

Comment: a public static method that will instantiate what you call an empty `NotificationNewDTO`. You can rename it as you wish.

Comment: Looks like I need to create it into NotificationNewDTO ? I get `The method ofDefaultValue() is undefined for the type NotificationNewDTO`. Can you give me sample what should be the content?

Comment: @Peter just create new object instead of that ofDefaultValue dude. It was supposed to be straight forward. You wanted an empty object. Just create one there.